# How do I get an HTML response from a Zapier catch hook

Tags: zapier

I have a zap that gets invoked by a URL sent to a user in an email. The user clicks on the url, that invokes the zap. The zap then does some work removing items from a google calendar. All that works perfectly. However, the user gets a JSON response like:

{ "status": "success", "attempt":    "58f76ead-ffa8-4807-b4a4-9cb31537ace0", "id":    "556d2bd7-e413-4fe0-9602-af4bfbba1f48", "request_id":    "zjd5zKTwCgtdDYS0" }

I would prefer that the user got an HTML response. Is this a javascript/python coding issue? Is there some unusually named zapier function that does this already?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to define the response content returned by requests made to a Zapier webhook URL. The response will always be a JSON response with basic status/meta data.

To get what you're looking for, you'd need to link your users to a webpage that will in turn make an HTTP request to Zapier when they visit.

Comment: Thanks Juan. Your solution is what I thought needed to be done, I just couldn't imagine that Zapier didn't already have a solution.